# Why is the formula $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\pi\in G} \phi(\pi)$ more useful than $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{s\in S} \eta(s)$? (Burnside's Lemma)

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I am reading "Introduction to Combinatorial Mathematics" by C. L. Liu.

The following theorem is in this book:

> Theorem 5-2 (Burnside)
> The number of equivalence classes into which a set $S$ is divided by the equivalence relation induced by a permutation group $G$ of $S$ is given by $$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\pi\in G} \phi(\pi)$$ where $\phi(\pi)$ is the number of elements that are invariant under the permutation $\pi$.

The following two sentences are from the proof of this theorem in this book:

> For any element $s$ in $S$, let $\eta(s)$ denote the number of permutations under which $s$ is invariant. Then $$\sum_{\pi\in G} \phi(\pi)=\sum_{s\in S} \eta(s)$$ because both $\sum_{\pi\in G} \phi(\pi)$ and $\sum_{s\in S} \eta(s)$ count the total number of invariances under all the permutations in $G$.

Why is the formula $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\pi\in G} \phi(\pi)$ more useful than $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{s\in S} \eta(s)$?

---

In this book, the author wrote an application of Burnside's Lemma:

> Example 5-2
> Find the number of distinct strings of length $2$ that are made up of blue beads and yellow beads. The two ends of a string are not marked, and two strings are, therefore, indistinguishable if interchanging the ends of one will yield the other. Let $b$ and $y$ denote blue and yellow beads, respectively. Let $bb,by,yb,$ and $yy$ denote the four different strings of length $2$ when equivalence between strings is not taken into consideration. The problem is to find the number of equivalence classes into which the set $S=\{bb,by,yb,yy\}$ is divided by the equivalence relation induced by the permutation group $G=\{\pi_1,\pi_2\}$, where $$\pi_1=\begin{pmatrix}bb & by & yb & yy\\bb & by & yb & yy\end{pmatrix}\text{   }\pi_2=\begin{pmatrix}bb & by & yb & yy\\bb & yb & by & yy\end{pmatrix}.$$
> The permutation $\pi_1$ merely indicates that every string is equivalent to itself, and the permutation $\pi_2$ indicates the equivalence between strings when the two ends of a string are interchanged. According to Burnside's theorem, the number of distinct strings is $$\frac{1}{2} (4+2)=3.$$

If we use the formula $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{s\in S} \eta(s)$, then we count as follows:
$$\frac{1}{2} (2+1+1+2)=3.$$

In this example, I don't think the formula $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\pi\in G} \phi(\pi)$ is more useful than $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{s\in S} \eta(s)$.

But when we write Burnside's Lemma, we write $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\pi\in G} \phi(\pi)$, but we don't write $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{s\in S} \eta(s)$.

I don't know why.

Comment: Not sure if there's really such a hyerarchy, but for an example where you can usefully use both jointly, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4136048/1007416

Comment: It depends on what you're counting and which way of grouping things makes the counting easier. Have you seen any applications of Burnside's Lemma?

Comment: @Karl Thank you very much for your comment. I edited my question.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo Thank you very much for your link to the example.

Comment: There might be an argument that summing over $G$ and dividing by $|G|$ is more aesthetically pleasing as it has the form of an average.  I rather doubt writing it one way over the other has to do with functionality.

Comment: Along the line suggested by @BrianMoehring, see *e.g.* here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4240957/1007416

Comment: Who wants to be the first to mention that this lemma is not due to Burnside, and in fact is Cauchy-Frobenius? I guess it's me. (It is often attributed to Burnside in older textbooks.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply, $\sum_{g\in G}\left|\text{Fix}(g)\right|$ is easier to compute than $\sum_{s\in S}\left|\text{Stab}(s)\right|$, because $G$ is typically much smaller than $S$.

Let's say you want to compute the number of inequivalent colorings of a cube up to rotation, where each face can be colored in one of $10$ colors. Letting $G$ be the group of symmetries of the cube, and $S$ be the set of colorings of a fixed cube ignoring symmetry, then $G$ acts on $S$, and we want to find the number of orbits of this action. We can compute this using either
$$
\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\left|\text{Fix}(g)\right|\quad \text{or}\quad \frac 1{|G|}\sum_{s\in S}\left|\text{Stab}(s)\right|
$$
Note that $|G|=24$, while $|S|=10^6$. Would you rather compute a sum of $24$ numbers, or a sum of a million numbers?

Comment: Furthermore, one can often split the sum over $G$ into a sum over conjugacy classes of $G$ and needs to consider only one representative per class.

Comment: Yes, but $\left|\operatorname{Stab}(s)\right|$ is constrained by Lagrange theorem, while $\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g)\right|$ in general isn't. For instance, if $|G|$ is a prime, the sum over (some huge) $S$ greatly symplifies.

Comment: You can calculate $|Fix(g)|$ typically with a combinatorial argument, considering the orbits of $g$.

Comment: What do you mean by "orbits of $g$", @ahulpke? Shouldn't rather orbits be "of $s$"?

Comment: @citadel. I mean the orbits (or cycles) of the subgroup $\langle g\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

When $S$ is also a group (so that $G$ acts on $S$ by automorphisms), then the usual "$\operatorname{Fix}$-version" of Burnside's lemma is potentially more insightful than the equivalent one with stabilizers' orders. If fact, in this case the fixed points sets *are also subgroups* (of $S$), and hence they benefit of the constraint provided by Lagrange's theorem. For example, [this argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4758047/1092170) wouldn't work with the "$\operatorname{Stab}$-version" of Burnside's lemma.